# each function to get the max of array of differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, max

I have this sample example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k2894um8/2/) .

```
  <div class="subchatarea2">
 <div  class='message_holder  user45 chatid28'>
<div class='likescore'>5</div><div class='unlikescore'>0</div>
</div>

<div  class='message_holder  user46 chatid29'>
<div class='likescore'>6</div><div class='unlikescore'>1</div>
</div>
<div  class='message_holder  user47 chatid30'>
<div class='likescore'>4</div><div class='unlikescore'>0</div>
</div>
<div  class='message_holder  user48 chatid31'>
<div class='likescore'>6</div><div class='unlikescore'>2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and my js is

```
 var his = $('.subchatarea2 .message_holder'); 

 var maxvoteups = [];
  var diff = his.children('.likescore').text()-his.children('.unlikescore').text(); 

 his.each(function() {

  maxvoteups.push(diff);
});
 var maxvoteup = Math.max.apply(Math, maxvoteups);
 alert(maxvoteup);
```

My wish is to get this result (array of differenses between upvote and downvote) like that :

```
  [5,5,4,4]
```

But in my page im getting

```
  [5544,5544,5544,5544]
```

and when i created this fiddle it gaves the result you are seen.

How can i get my wish result `[5,5,4,4]` because in further i wanna select the max upvoted with min downvoted

```
 var maxvoteup = Math.max.apply(Math, maxvoteups);
```

and then i wanna get the first `5` because the second 5 has downvote 1 and the first one has downvote 0 .

How can i accomplish this thanks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var his = $('.subchatarea2 .message_holder'); 

 var maxvoteups = []; 

 his.each(function() {
  var diff = $(this).children('.likescore').text() - $(this).children('.unlikescore').text();
  var downvotes = $(this).children('.unlikescore').text();
  maxvoteups.push([diff, downvotes]);
});
```

Now you have a list like this :

```
[[5,0], [6,1], [4,0],[6,2]]
```

wich is `[[totalvotes(total_up - total_down), total_downvotes]]`

EDIT :
Better than this is make a list of objects :

```
 var his = $('.subchatarea2 .message_holder'); 

 var maxvoteups = []; 

 his.each(function() {
  var diff = $(this).children('.likescore').text() - $(this).children('.unlikescore').text();
  var downvotes = $(this).children('.unlikescore').text();
  maxvoteups.push({total : diff, down : downvotes});
});
```

Then a function to compare objects :

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.total > b.total)
    return -1;
  else if (a.total < b.total)
    return 1;
  else if (a.down > b.down) // If a has more downvotes the a is under b.
    return -1;
  else if (a.down < b.down)
    return 1;
}
```

Now order the list like this :

```
maxvoteups.sort(compare);
```

### EDIT

Final code :

```
var his = $('.subchatarea2 .message_holder');

var maxvoteups = [];

his.each(function() {
  var diff = $(this).children('.likescore').text() - $(this).children('.unlikescore').text();
  var downvotes = $(this).children('.unlikescore').text();
  var upvotes = $(this).children('.likescore').text();
  var node = $(this);
  maxvoteups.push({total : diff, downvotes : downvotes, upvotes : upvotes, node : node});

});
//var maxvoteup = Math.max.apply(Math, maxvoteups);
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.total > b.total)
    return -1;
  else if (a.total < b.total)
    return 1;
  else if (a.down < b.down)
    return -1;
  else if (a.down > b.down)
    return 1;
}
maxvoteups.sort(compare);
alert('The max value is : ' + maxvoteups[0].total + ' with ' +  maxvoteups[0].upvotes + ' upvotes and ' +  maxvoteups[0].downvotes + ' downvotes and is the jquery element ' +  maxvoteups[0].node );

maxvoteups.forEach(function(post, index){
    alert('The' + (index + 1) + ' value of the sorted list is : ' + post.total + ' with ' +            post.upvotes + ' upvotes and ' +  post.downvotes + ' downvotes and is the jquery element ' +  post.node );
});
```

Comment: and how do i get  `[5,0]` the one with min downvotes . ?

Comment: See edit. This can be done better with an array of objects.

Comment: I was wrong with the two first comparisons in compare function. I updated the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k2894um8/11/ . Now for example you can acces to the max value like this maxvotesup[0] or to get the total value (diff) maxvotesup[0].total  and the downvotes maxvotesup[0].down

Comment: couldnt get the max from your code . can you modify your fiddle so it gives the propper result thanks ?

Comment: I loop trough the array that is sorted as you want, to print the content of the objects. If you want to get the max value just maxvotesup[0].total, but choose the @Thomas answer.

Comment: i liked your simple answer, it looks difficult for me his answer , would you like to edit the fiddle and alert the wished result ?

Comment: updated fidlle, now you get the same approach of Thomas answer : https://jsfiddle.net/k2894um8/28/

Comment: Actually thank you for posting and thomas for teaching us. I learned too with this post! :)

Comment: How does your function `function compare(a,b)` works ? because i didnt see you using a and b , when you call it. and what is a and b ?    thanks

Comment: your function doesnt order really exact , if i have uv : 7 and dv:2 , and uv:8 and dv:3  then your function returns (8 : 3) which is wrong , it should return (7:2) . i have tried to change < > between every thing but nothing helped , i guess something with else if , can you help and explain it for me pls .

Comment: Type Error : a.down was undefined in compare function : The correct property was a.downvotes ; Check fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k2894um8/31/

Answer (score 3):

same intention as @Jose, but different implementation

```
var his = $('.subchatarea2 .message_holder'); 
var $votes = his.map(function(i, node){
    //first parse the text in the DOM into some data-structure
    var $node = $(node);
    return {
        node: $node,
        up: +$node.children('.likescore').text(),
        down: +$node.children('.unlikescore').text(),
        get diff(){
            return this.up - this.down;
        }
    };
}).sort(function(a, b){
    //and sort it by: `diff` desc, `down` asc
    return b.diff - a.diff || a.down - b.down;
});

//so your prefered value is at index 0
console.log("maxvoteup", $votes[0]);
console.log("votes", $votes);
```

Comment: Its at index 0 but i want calculate it automatically not just put index 0 .

Comment: $votes is sorted, so that the element with the highest diff, and the least downvote will always be at index 0, at 1 is the second best, ... the last entry in votes will have the "worst" vote; low diff, highest downvotes

Comment: Wow pretty implementation!!  I thought too to pass the node to the object what makes sense. But this is pretty nice!

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo but it gives wrong alert in his fiddle i gave him

Comment: Actually no, diff is defined as a getter (perfect ES5-Syntax). But unlike `console.log()`, `alert()` doesn't handle multiple arguments, and also doesn't handle Objects very well (doesn't stringify them, nor gives you the ability to inspect them). The Error is actually simply replacing `console.log` with `alert` without fixing this. [try it yourself](//jsfiddle.net/k2894um8/26/)

Comment: +1 Thomas for your simple code But its difficult for me this map and node , so i go with Joses answer . thanks so much , i know yours is better but i want something that i know.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, plz. read [the reference to getter](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). If this getter bothers you, precompute the value and make it a regular property, or compute the total in the sort-method on the fly. This is no place to use a simple function.

Comment: Yes! I searched it when you commented previously. For that reason I upvoted your comment! I didn't know that this could be done! Please ignore the edit! Thanks again! =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the `diff` variable inside the loop

```
 var his = $('.subchatarea2 .message_holder'); 
 var maxvoteups = [];
 var = 0;

 his.each(function() {
     diff = his.children('.likescore').text()-his.children('.unlikescore').text(); 
      maxvoteups.push(diff);
    });
 var maxvoteup = Math.max.apply(Math, maxvoteups);
 alert(maxvoteups);
```

Answer (score 0):

A plain JS version would be nothing more than just 3 lines of variable assinments. something like;

```js
var    his = Array(...document.querySelectorAll('.subchatarea2 .message_holder')),
maxvoteups = his.map( e => e.firstElementChild.innerText - e.lastElementChild.innerText),
 maxvoteup = Math.max(...maxvoteups);

document.write("<pre>Array Values: " + maxvoteups + " Max Upvote: " + maxvoteup + "</pre>");
```

```html
<div class="subchatarea2">
  <div  class='message_holder  user45 chatid28'>
    <div class='likescore'>5</div>
    <div class='unlikescore'>0</div>
  </div>
  <div  class='message_holder  user46 chatid29'>
    <div class='likescore'>6</div>
    <div class='unlikescore'>1</div>
  </div>
  <div  class='message_holder  user47 chatid30'>
    <div class='likescore'>4</div>
    <div class='unlikescore'>0</div>
  </div>
  <div  class='message_holder  user48 chatid31'>
    <div class='likescore'>6</div>
    <div class='unlikescore'>2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```